# How to finish activity when slide it down like facebook image gallery , activity that holds Viewpager so it consumes onTouch event

Tags: android, android-viewpager, gesturedetector

i need to finish up activity when its scroll down to up & up to down(like Facebook gallery)
structure of screen,
Activity > View pager, that have one image view with zooming functionality.

when i m using Gesture Detector with activity all works fine but after adding view pager its fail. I have searched a lot but negative. Is there any solution?
Here is my snippet, when i set adpater to viewpager activity onTouch listener is not being called.
To handle pinch to zoom,m using [https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

//Activity Class

```
public class ViewPagerFullScreenActivity extends BaseActivity{
ViewPager pager;
ArrayList<String> arrayList;
int position;
private ViewSliderAdapter siderAdapter;
RelativeLayout relative;
GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pager_full_screen);
    initControls();
    mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new MyGestureListener());
}

private void initControls() {
   //set init controls
}

private void getIntentValues() {
   //get array list and values
}

@Override 
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){ 
    this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}


class ViewSliderAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ViewSliderAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        ImageFullContent imageFullContent = new ImageFullContent();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("URL", arrayList.get(position));
        imageFullContent.setArguments(b);
        return imageFullContent;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }
}

class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures";

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"onDown: " + event.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
                           float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onFling: " + event1.toString()+event2.toString());
        return true;
    }
  }


 }
```

//Simple Fragment Class

```
 public class ImageFullContent extends Fragment {

PhotoView imageView;
String URL;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_full_content, container, false);
    initControls(view);
    return view;
}

private void initControls(View view){
      //init controls and load image with glide
      //for zooming i have used custom PhotoView
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance!